# C++, return duplicate instances from an array to a string

Tags: c++, arrays

Background to this: This is not homework, it's completely optional review for a basic c++ class. As I want to pass, I'm going through each example the best I can, This one I'm super stuck on, and have been for about three hours now.

Problem: Write a function to return a string composed of the most frequent lowercase letter found in each row of a 10 x 10 array of lowercase alphabetic chars in the range a through z.

If there is more than one most frequent character, use the one that come first alphabetically.

Use neither cin nor cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string mostFrequent(char c[10][10]){
// this is the function I need to create
}

int main(){
    char c[10][10] = {
    'a','b','f','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
    'a','b','c','r','c','r','g','h','r','j',
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','o','o',
    'z','w','p','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
    'o','d','o','d','o','b','o','d','o','d',
    'a','l','l','d','e','f','f','h','l','j',
    'a','b','c','d','i','f','g','h','i','j',
    'a','b','z','v','z','v','g','g','v','z',
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','e',
    'a','b','s','d','e','f','g','h','s','j',
    };

cout << mostFrequent(c) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

So in research for this I found some material that allows me to count how many times a specific int or char would appear inside the array, but it doesn't quite suit the needs of the problem as it needs to return a string composed of the most frequent character. See below.

int myints[] = {10,20,30,30,20,10,10,20};

int mycount = std::count (myints, myints+8, 10);

Because it doesn't work though, I was thinking a for loop, to go row to row, I'll mostly likely need to save things into an array to count, but I'm not sure at all how to implement something like that. I even considered a caesar shift with an array, but I'm not sure where to go if that is the solution.

Comment: Do you have a problem with: A) figuring the algorithm, or B) you know the algorithm for this, but having a problem translating it to C++. In the former's case, your question would not have anything to do with C++, then. In the latter case, you should post whatever code you have managed to write, and explain exactly which parts you can't figure out how to do. In either case, stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the task correctly, you have a matrix 10x10 and you have to create a string of length 10, where character at position `i` is the one that is most frequent among characters in the row `i`.

```
string mostFrequent(char c[10][10])  {
  // The idea here is to find the most common character in each row and then append that character to the string
  string s = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s += findMostFrequentCharacter(c[i]);
  return s;
}
```

Now we just have to implement a function `char findMostFrequentCharacter(char c)`. We are going to do that by counting all of the characters and picking the one that is most frequent (or it comes alphabetically before if there is more than one most frequent character):

```
char findMostFrequentCharacter(char c[10]) {
  int counts[256]; // Assuming these are ASCII characters, we can have max 256 different values
  // Fill it with zeroes (you can use memset to do that, but for clarity I'll write a for-loop
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) c[i] = 0;

  // Do the actual counting
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // For each character
    counts[ c[i] ]++;  // Increase it's count by 1, note that c[i] is going to have values between 65 (upper case A) and 122 (lower case z)

  char mostFrequent = 0;
  // Find the one that is most frequent

  for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'z' ch++) // This will ensure that we iterate over all upper and lower case letters (+ some more but we don't care about it)
    if (counts[ch] > counts[c]) c = ch;  // Take the one that is more frequent, note that in case they have the same count nothing will happen which is what we want since we are iterating through characters in alphabetical order
  return c;
}
```

I have written the code out of my head so I'm sorry if there are any compile errors.

Comment: I definitely see what my code was missing the counts[256] is definitely more elegant than the +96 or -96 that I was attempting, that and the for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s += findMostFrequentCharacter(c[i]); you have, I completely whiffed, that makes perfect sense, you are ten types of awesome,

Comment: @NathanRaine Save yourself a for loop: `int counts[256] = {0};` will initialize the first element of the array to 0 and then, because there are more elements that have not had a value defined in the braces, set the rest of the array to the default of 0. You can have all sorts of fun with this like `int counts[256] = {1,2,3};` First three elements are 1, 2, and 3 respectively and the rest will be zero.